# Weak wifi signal with Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell Vostro 5468, Intel wireless 3165

Tags: wireless, laptop, compatibility

My Dell has an Intel Wireless 3165. It is found during installation, and `dmesg` reports:

```
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.361476.0 op_mode iwlmvm
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0x210
```

I don't know if those first errors are normal, but it appears to find a useful one and then gets the wifi up running. However, when I start a download the speed is basically none, and in System Monitor I just see a few Kb spike in the curve every 30 seconds or so.

I go to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and start by turning off 11n:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
#options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8
#options iwlwifi wd_disable=1
#options iwlwifi lar_disable=1
options iwlwifi power_save=0
#options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0
#options antenna_coupling=0 
#options swcrypto=1
```

(The commented out lines are what I found in other suggestions for how to make it work, and I have tried them in different combinations, but no improvement. I have not found out what `antenna_coupling` actually does -- it is in dB so I hoped that it could adjust the strength of the antenna but that was of course wishful thinking. The `power_save` option does not seem to do anything, so I had to add a line in crontab to turn it off, which works.)

Now I can download at a somewhat normal speed. If I sit a meter away from the router I get 3 staples for the signal strength. If I move into the next room behind a wooden wall it stays at 3, but at 5 meters distance and behind another wooden wall, it goes down to 2 and dl speed goes to 0. Then I occasionally lose the wifi altogether. At the exact same spot I get 4 staples with Windows 10 on the same computer (and with my Macbook).

I tried with and without Bluetooth but that does not seem to change anything (I have a mouse that can run either Bluetooth or dongle, and with Bluetooth it sometimes hangs for a second or two). (The Intel 3165 card has Bluetooth integrated.)

I can live with no 11n (although it seems buggy that it is not supported by Ubuntu). But the signal strength issue is very real and should not be there. Does anyone know what else I can do to solve it?

I tried with a live Ubuntu 17.04 but same problem.

Addition:

`modinfo iwlwifi` returns the following:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-46-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-IWL6000G2B_UCODE_API_MAX.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C--24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-a0-lc-a0--24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-a0-jf-a0--24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-lc-a0--24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0--24.ucode
srcversion:     E7651FD3D9AF45F96CD8B2E<
```

The firmware that is actually being used, `iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode`, is not in that list, which only has `iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode`. Now, even when I download the complete `iwlwifi` firmware package from kernel.org, it has no version numbered 24. There is 22 and then 27. What to make of that? Does it matter?

Comment: ps: one of your problems has to do with the Nvidia driver that you used. The latest version, obtained directly from Nvidia, has a bug. You should use the Nvidia driver from the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Thanks heynnema, I understand and fixed the text. Thanks for the Nvidia driver advice, will try it.

Comment: The messages about failed firmware loading are fine as long as at least one succeeds.

Answer (score 2):

I own and use successfully two Intel wireless devices. I have honed a few techniques in several years and thousands of forum posts.

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Finally, Network Manager will default to ethernet if it's available. Please make your tests with the ethernet detached.

EDIT: I believe the more recent firmware can be found in the latest *linux-firmware* package. Please open a terminal and do:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.164_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Reboot and let us hear your results.

Comment: Thanks, Chili555. I did all those things but the signal still remains as weak as before, unfortunately.

Comment: When you run `sudo iwlist scan` at your usual spot, I assume "...at 5 meters distance and behind another wooden wall..." what does the quality read? 50/70 or 40/70 or what? http://paste.ubuntu.com/24444498/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24444571/

Comment: Checked again: Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm. 

When I then try to download something (from a good server in the same city) I get no dl speed at all, basically.  

At exactly the same spot, as I said, I get almost full signal with Windows (on the same computer) and with a Macbook.

If I then move the computer until 1-2 meters from the router, in the same room as the router, I get 1-2 mbps dl speed.

Comment: I noticed in your pastes that you've going between 2.4ghz and 5ghz bands. 5ghz is a more robust method, but won't go as far as 2.4ghz. 2.4ghz is more susceptible to interference and cross-channel problems with neighboring  wireless networks. You should try stationary channels 1/6/11 in 2.4ghz band, and try 40 in 5ghz. Lastly, just to check... is your MTU set to 1500 in BOTH the Ubuntu and in your router?

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: Heynnema, the first paste was not mine but by chili555. I have set my router to channel 1 (not auto) and use only 2.4 ghz as far as I can see. The MTU is set to 1500 on the router and auto on the computer.

Comment: Chili555: I cloned from here: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git

which i guess would give me the latest fw. But I tried your way too. No difference in any case, though.

Comment: I am now suspecting that there is a bug in the firmware or driver for iwlwifi that makes this specific card not working properly.